# Seeing high CPU spikes in MapBox using SQLite3_Step

Tags: xcode, sqlite, cpu, mapbox, route-me

I'm currently getting a tiling issue in MapBox and it looks like a bottleneck issue with the following code:

```
rc      = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
```

in the following function:

```
- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql error:(NSError**)outErr withArgumentsInArray:(NSArray*)arrayArgs orDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryArgs orVAList:(va_list)args
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, this issue can sometimes take up to 2-3 seconds to complete:

[image: CPU Usage]

I have noticed that my code seems to perform this function in bursts. So the CPU will drop to about 10% before spiking up to 100+%. During the time it spikes the MapTiles are drawn, however, before this the map drawing comes to a complete stop. This can happen 2-3 times before the tiles are all drawn.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Not sure if it's my CoreData calls interrupting the MapBox ones?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `1.5.0` version, released just today, which improves disk caching performance and might address this for you.

Comment: Hi incanus, that fixed a lot of the memory issues thank you. There is still slight more usage than I would like but that's probably due to my CoreData calls, am looking at neatening them now.